# TypeScript: Type inference when using string literals

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Please have a look at the following TypeScript code.
It's clear that the type inference behaves like described in the comments.

Now the question: Is it somehow possible to change the definition of `type V2 = ...` in a way, that it infers to type `"someOtherValue"` and not to `string` in general any longer?

As far as I understand TypeScript's type inference, this is absolutely NOT possible ... but who knows, maybe I am wrong.
To be on the safe side I better ask the TypeScript community for help. Thanks.

```js
const config1 = { value: 'someValue' as const } 

type K1 = keyof typeof config1      // type K1: "value" (not string in general)
type V1 = (typeof config1)['value'] // type V1: "someValue" (not string in general)

const config2 = { value: 'someOtherValue' } 

type K2 = keyof typeof config2      // type K2: "value" (not string in general)
type V2 = (typeof config2)['value'] // type V2: string
```

TypeScript Playground: [Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKYDMCWBzAjDAvDA3jAbgIYA2ArgKYBcMA5BCALbkBqJFNMhEc40MAvjACwAKFFQAngAdyMANIZsAa3ISQCGJJnqeiVBhiHDAemObpshdQBERMuWswAFGBCxoAJyRgUMbzBRyMHIPEgBKcQsYZkVnLXIdeGR0MIBtGjt2AF0YU3MZaLQbeiZWe0cXNxhPb19-QODQ4gixEXg+JNQAJixcAjYqWhLyAHkoAAsQsvYBYVb4+R7lVR14xPBknqMTMwW5LptMh2dXdygvHz8wAKCQ8MiC5iW4i3W9FC60jIGaHLyFp7UGo+IA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to cast `const` on the whole `config2` too.

```js
const config2 = { value: 'someOtherValue' } as const;
```

otherwise it always will be string.

---

with the key access

```js
const config1 = { value: 'someValue' as const } 

type K1 = keyof typeof config1      // type K1: "value" (not string in general)
type V1 = (typeof config1)['value'] // type V1: "someValue" (not string in general)

const config2 = { value: 'someOtherValue' } as const;

type K2 = keyof typeof config2 // type K2: "value" (not string in general)
type V2 = (typeof config2)[K2] // type V2: "someOtherValue"
```

Comment: @ satanTime + @ JózefPodlecki: To write that `as const` not after the string itself but after the object literal is actually quite a nice idea. In my actual use case - which is a bit more complicated that that simple example ;-) - there is a function that gets  a large configuration object as argument, and there I do not want to write `as const` a dozens time after some special strings... but if I just write `as const` one time after the large configuration object, type inference works as desired. Thank you very much guys, you were really a big help :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Now the question: Is it somehow possible to change the definition of
>   type V2 = ... in a way, that it infers to type "someOtherValue" and
>   not to string in general any longer?

[Yes, you have to tell typescript that type is not going to change with const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). You can either apply it to the value prop or the whole object as @satanTime suggested.

Why? Because typescript assumes you might do following thing.

```js
const config2 = { value: 'someOtherValue' } 
config2.value = "something different"
```

With const assertion applied type checker can decide to do type narrowing.

```js
const config1 = { value: 'someValue' as const } 
config1.value = "test" // Type '"test"' is not assignable to type '"someValue"'.
const config2 = { value: 'someOtherValue' } as const
config2.value = "test" // Cannot assign to 'value' because it is a read-only property.
```